# How to not overwrite child in firebase and view previous data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how can I not overwrite my child in my firebase database because whenever user is going back to chatroom the child of my firebase is overwriting causing the past messages is deleted. Can someone please help me? Thaaanks.

Here is the code to the chat room.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put(pref.getString("username", "").toString()+" chats "+tvOwnerUser.getText().toString(),"");
                root.updateChildren(map);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Chat_Room.class);
                intent.putExtra("room_name","Car No"+tvID123.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("user_name", pref.getString("username", ""));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

and the chatroom

```
public class Chat_Room extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btn_send_msg;
private EditText input_msg;
private TextView chat_conversation;

private String user_name, room_name;
private DatabaseReference root;
private String temp_key;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat_room);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    btn_send_msg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    input_msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg_input);
    chat_conversation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    user_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name").toString();
    room_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("room_name").toString();
    setTitle("Chat");

    root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(room_name);

    btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            temp_key = root.push().getKey();
            root.updateChildren(map);

            DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
            Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            map2.put("name", user_name);
            map2.put("msg", input_msg.getText().toString());

            message_root.updateChildren(map2);
            input_msg.setText("");
        }
    });

    root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

**private String chat_msg,chat_user_name;**



 private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()){
            chat_msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
            chat_user_name = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();

            chat_conversation.append(chat_user_name +" : "+chat_msg +" \n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of an answer Hahaha!!

```
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(root.child("Car No"+tvID123.getText().toString()).getRoot() == null){
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put(pref.getString("username", "").toString()+" chats "+tvOwnerUser.getText().toString(),"");
                root.updateChildren(map);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Chat_Room.class);
                intent.putExtra("room_name","Car No"+tvID123.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("user_name", pref.getString("username", ""));
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Chat_Room.class);
                intent.putExtra("room_name","Car No"+tvID123.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("user_name", pref.getString("username", ""));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code may be it will help you

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(room_name);
            final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            String key = root.push().getKey();
            root.updateChildren(map);

            DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(key);
            Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map2.put("name", "Sarvan");
            map2.put("msg", "Message");
            message_root.updateChildren(map2);
            root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    list.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String name = (String) snapshot.child("name").getValue();
                        String message = (String) snapshot.child("msg").getValue();
                        mapList.put("name", name);
                        mapList.put("msg", message);
                        list.add(mapList);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

}